# How to add sql file in oracle database 11g?

Tags: java, oracle, swing

I have been created java register using java swing:

Here is registration.java code:

```
   package student;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.sql.*;

public class Registration extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{ 

  JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8;

  JTextField tf1, tf2, tf5, tf6, tf7;

  JButton btn1, btn2;

  JPasswordField p1, p2;



  Registration()
   {

      setVisible(true);

      setSize(700, 700);

      setLayout(null);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      setTitle("Registration Form in Java");



      l1 = new JLabel("Registration Form in Windows Form:");

      l1.setForeground(Color.blue);

      l1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
      l2 = new JLabel("Name:");

      l3 = new JLabel("Email-ID:");

      l4 = new JLabel("Create Passowrd:");

      l5 = new JLabel("Confirm Password:");

      l6 = new JLabel("Country:");

      l7 = new JLabel("State:");

      l8 = new JLabel("Phone No:"); 

      tf1 = new JTextField();

      tf2 = new JTextField();

      p1 = new JPasswordField();

      p2 = new JPasswordField();

      tf5 = new JTextField();

      tf6 = new JTextField();

      tf7 = new JTextField();



      btn1 = new JButton("Submit");

      btn2 = new JButton("Clear");



      btn1.addActionListener(this);

      btn2.addActionListener(this);



      l1.setBounds(100, 30, 400, 30);

      l2.setBounds(80, 70, 200, 30);

      l3.setBounds(80, 110, 200, 30);

      l4.setBounds(80, 150, 200, 30);

      l5.setBounds(80, 190, 200, 30);

      l6.setBounds(80, 230, 200, 30);

      l7.setBounds(80, 270, 200, 30);

      l8.setBounds(80, 310, 200, 30);

      tf1.setBounds(300, 70, 200, 30);
      tf2.setBounds(300, 110, 200, 30);

      p1.setBounds(300, 150, 200, 30);

      p2.setBounds(300, 190, 200, 30);

      tf5.setBounds(300, 230, 200, 30);

      tf6.setBounds(300, 270, 200, 30);

      tf7.setBounds(300, 310, 200, 30);

      btn1.setBounds(50, 350, 100, 30);

      btn2.setBounds(170, 350, 100, 30);
      add(l1);

      add(l2);

      add(tf1);

      add(l3);

      add(tf2);

      add(l4);

      add(p1);

      add(l5);

      add(p2);

      add(l6);

      add(tf5);

      add(l7);

      add(tf6);

      add(l8);

      add(tf7);

      add(btn1);

      add(btn2);

  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

     if (e.getSource() == btn1)
      {

         int x = 0;

         String s1 = tf1.getText();

         String s2 = tf2.getText();



         char[] s3 = p1.getPassword();

         char[] s4 = p2.getPassword(); 

         String s8 = new String(s3);

         String s9 = new String(s4);



         String s5 = tf5.getText();

         String s6 = tf6.getText();

         String s7 = tf7.getText();

         if (s8.equals(s9))
        {

             try
            {

                 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:rajesh/local@localhost");
                 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into emp values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                 ps.setString(1, s1);

                 ps.setString(2, s2);

                 ps.setString(3, s8);

                 ps.setString(4, s5);

                 ps.setString(5, s6);

                 ps.setString(6, s7);

                 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                 x++;

                 if (x > 0)
                 {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn1, "Data Saved Successfully");

                 }

             }
       catch (Exception ex)
             {

                 System.out.println(ex);

             }

         }
       else
        {

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn1, "Password Does Not Match");

         } 

     } else
     {

         tf1.setText("");

         tf2.setText("");

         p1.setText("");

         p2.setText("");

         tf5.setText("");

         tf6.setText("");

         tf7.setText("");

     }

 } 

 public static void main(String args[])
{

     new Registration();

 }
}
```

When i run this, it shows

```
"ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".
```

But i have created database user and table in oracle 11g.

These steps are i did in sql command line:

```
connect
username:
password:
"connected"
create user rani identifed by pcs;
grant connect, resource to rani;
"granted"
```

After that, for creating table, i have a file called reg.sql:

```
create table emp
 (
    name varchar2(30), email varchar2(40),
    pass varchar2(30), count varchar2(30),
    state varchar2(30), phone number(15)
 );
```

So i have to import this file for store student details.

May i know, how to do this,? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> connect
> username:
> password:
> "connected"
> create user rani identifed by pcs;
> grant connect, resource to rani;
> "granted"
> create table reg(pid integer primary key,name varchar2(50));
> "table created"
> ```

You have created the table not in the **RANI schema**. You need to first **connect** to RANI user and then issue the **CREATE TABLE** statement. As of now, your table REG resides in the **USER** that you initially connected to.

**Update** Based on OP's request about executing the script.

You could execute it as a script. Just add everything in the script itself and call the script.

For example, your `reg.sql` would look like this:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE emp';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
create table emp
 (
    name varchar2(30), email varchar2(40),
    pass varchar2(30), count varchar2(30),
    state varchar2(30), phone number(15)
 );
```

You just need to execute the script with the complete directory where it is placed locally. Let's say the **reg.sql** is placed in **C:\REG**

```
sqlplus -s rani/pcs@sid << EOF
@C:\REG\reg.sql;
EXIT;
EOF
```

Comment: Your code still says `insert into reg`, Once again, does `reg` table exists? Which table do you want to really insert into?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72822/discussion-between-sona-and-lalit-kumar-b).

Comment: Ok, this is one last time I am telling you repeatedly. Once you are connected to SQL*Plus, you don't ahve to use the keyword SQL*Plus again. Let's say you have created user `rajesh` with password as `local`. Do `CONNECT`. Enter `RAJESH` as username and enter `local` as password. Once you are connected to RAJESH user, then `@c:\file`

Comment: yes i got it.. thanks.. then how to view my data in database?.. thanks

Comment: i want to view like this http://s8.postimg.org/y4lchfxqd/Untitled_2_copy.png, i mean i want to view in oracle database engine.. thanks

Comment: Open a new question as this is different from your original question. I could answer there

Comment: but it is simple one, for that create new question is not correct,, its ok,, i will find.. thank you so much for spending your time..

Comment: You could view the table via tool like SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. After you connect to the RAJESH user in sqlplus, issue `select * from table_name`. It will list down all the rows. Else, if you have SQL Developer, you could directly view the objects in the left of objects pane.

Comment: i used select * from emp; but nothing shows.. and i download sql developer .. and when i run sqldeveloper.exe, it  asks "specifies the path".

Comment: I have raised one more question, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025971/how-to-view-the-input-data-in-oracle-11g-in-java-swing .. can you please help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create your table into `rani` schema. For java it can as below:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:rani/pcs@localhost");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("create table ...");
```

Comment: i can't understand, for creating table.. because i m new to java.. i have reg.sql file.. may i know ,is there way to import my project.?

Comment: @sona, exeute your script with `statement.executeUpdate(myScriptFromRegSQL);`

Comment: @ Michael Kazarian: i heard need sql developer to import sql file.. is it right?

Comment: @sona, yes, you can execute script from SQL Developer or from [SQL Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#XEDEV10000). My answer about create table from your own code.

Comment: ok. how to change with my existing code, i mean my posted code? thanks

Comment: but, i download the sql developer and when i run sqldeveloper.exe, it asks "specifies the path"..